# KVC select by criteria

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, key-value-coding

I have a array of objects that selected from core data. I need select from this set subset of object that correspond to condition.
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read you correctly you want to filter your array based on a condition met by some of the objects in it?

You can do this by using `NSPredicate` and call `filteredArrayWithPredicate:` on your array.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute == YES"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayWithPredicate:predicate];
```

You can read more about using predicates in the [Predicates Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html)

You can also use predicates to filter your `NSFetchRequest` directly when retrieving the data from Core Data.